# My button will not execute the command it is assigned to in Tkinter

Tags: button, tkinter, python-3.3

The button now will do something. It gives an error and won't execute.

```
class FCHSapp(tk.Frame):
def __init__(self, parent, controller):
    tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
    LARGE_FONT=("Verdana", 30)
    label = tk.Label(self, text="FCHS Teacher Login", font=LARGE_FONT)
    label.pack(pady=10,padx=10)
    entry1 = tk.Entry(self, textvariable=var, width = 35, font=LARGE_FONT)
    entry1.pack()
    labelb = tk.Label(self, text="    ", font=LARGE_FONT)
    labelb.pack()
    button1 = tk.Button(self, text="Login", command=lambda: self.code_run, width = 30, font=LARGE_FONT)
    button1.pack()
    button2 = tk.Button(self, text="Print Absent/Tardy Teachers", command=lambda: controller.show_frame(PrintSC), width = 30, font=LARGE_FONT)
    button2.pack()
def code_run(self):
    user = var.get()
    for i in codes.keys():
        if user == i:
            if codes[user][1] == 0:
                import os
                from time import gmtime, strftime
                time = strftime("%H:%M:%S", gmtime())
                print(time)
                my_file = open("Login.txt", "w")
                name = codes[user][0]
                my_file.write(name)
                my_file.write(" ")
                my_file.write(time)
                my_file.close()
                os.startfile("C:/Users/ILCASA01/Desktop/Login Files/Login.txt", "print")
                codes[user][1] = 1
```

Here's the error that appears. I do not understand what it means. The code itself should process the entry and print a name. But when I execute it only gives me the error

Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python33\lib\tkinter__init__.py", line 1442, in **call**
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\ILCASA01\Desktop\Login Files\Loginv2.5 GUI Version.py", line 156, in 
    button1 = tk.Button(self, text="Login", command=lambda: self.code_run(cont), width = 30, font=LARGE_FONT)
NameError: global name 'cont' is not defined

Also i'm so sorry for not making it look neater.

Comment: Is `code_run` an instance method? Should that be `self.code_run(cont)`?

Comment: Don't be sorry for not making it neater -- take the time to make it look neater. If you're not willing to put in the effort to make your question easy to read, why should we take the time to answer it?

Answer (score 0):

You have at least two problems. One, you are calling the function as `code_run(self, ...)` when it should be `self.code_run(...)`.

Second, you have no variable named `cont`. Perhaps you meant `controller`?

lambdas are difficult to debug. You should avoid using them unless there is no other choice. In this case I would make `controller` an attribute (eg: `self.controller`) and let the called function use it rather than have it passed in. Then your button becomes `Button(..., command=self.code_run)`, which will be easier to debug.

```
class FCHSapp(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.controller = controller
        ...
```

Comment: This may seem like a very newby question, but where would I make an attribute? Also now when I run it, it gives me an error

Comment: @Leonard10: in your `__init__`, just do `self.controller = controller`.